# Python3 filter numbers in specific range from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a little program with `tkinter` which organizes the available cars a dealership has. I have a `.txt` file which contains the cars like this:

```
Item number: 0001
Brand: BMW
Model: 320i
Year: 2010
Price: 14500

Item Number: 0002
Brand: AUDI
Model: A3
Year: 2016
Price: 27000
```

If I only want cars which are in the price range of 10,000-15,000, I want to go trough the list and copy all cars which are in the price range. After I ask for the price in the other part of my program the code is built like this:

```
#gets the price from Entry field
pricefrom = enterprfrom.get()
priceto = enterprto.get()

f = open("cars.txt", "r")
list = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in range(len(list)):
   if list[line[4]] >= pricefrom and liste[linie]<= priceto:
```

So at that point I want to try to check if the price in the 4th line is between 10,000-15,000.
If it is, I need to copy the lines 0-4, and move to line 9 for the next car. Can somebody help me with my problem? The last line of my code doesn't work properly and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the file such that each key value pair ends up in a dictionary, and then you can look up the price field on the dictionary. Every time you get to "item number" you should work on the next dict. I also notice the capitalization is inconsistent on keys, so you should normalize them all to lower.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

with open("cars.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

items = defaultdict(dict)

curr_item_num = None
for line in lines:
    elements = line.split(":")
    if len(elements) == 2:
        key, value = elements[0].strip().lower(), elements[1].strip()
        if key == "item number":
            curr_item_num = value
        items[curr_item_num][key] = value

pprint(dict(items))
```

```
{'0001': {'brand': 'BMW',
          'item number': '0001',
          'model': '320i',
          'price': '14500',
          'year': '2010'},
 '0002': {'brand': 'AUDI',
          'item number': '0002',
          'model': 'A3',
          'price': '27000',
          'year': '2016'}}
```

Now its easy to do your test:

```
for item in items.values():
    if pricefrom <= item["price"] <= priceto:
        # your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your list is as you wrote your code would be:

```
#gets the price from Entry field
pricefrom = 10000
priceto = 15000

f = open("cars.txt", "r")
list = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in range(len(list)):
   print(list[line])
   if(list[line].split(":")[0] == "Price"):
      if int(list[line].split(":")[1]) >= pricefrom and int(list[line].split(":")[1]) <= priceto:
         print("yes")
```

you put your list[line][4] wrong and didn't think of the label.